# Android: How to resize numberpicker?

Tags: android, resize, scale, numberpicker

I'm new to android programming and I need to resize the NumberPicker widget, the current code for the NumberPicker widget is

```
<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/np"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

the problem is that it has a fixed width and height, and I want to edit them..
But, if you set a width or height, the numberpicker will not scale properly

e.g.

```
    android:width:"100dp"
```

will give you a oddly shaped number picker

So I thought of using ScaleX and ScaleY but that isn't very reliable/**accurate** although it works

```
    scaleX="0.5"
    scaleY="0.5"
```

So, what I want to know is that: is there an accurate way of setting the numberpicker's width and height with scaling? (I can't use ScaleType also cause that's for ImageView)

Comment: Hi, i hope you solved this issue. Please share your answer

Comment: I am also having the same issue. I need the solution, if you have found then please share .